# Unable to start a task on Amazon ECS - EC2 Launch Type with Windows Server 2019

Tags: windows, containers, amazon-ecs

I have been trying to deploy a .NET Framework 4.8 application on an Amazon ECS cluster with Windows Server 2019 instances. However, the task does not start up. Upon RDPing into the ECS instance and looking at the Event Viewer, I saw the following errors.

[image]

[image]

It appears that the start container API timed out due to a syscall timeout. I am not sure what is the exact problem though. To rule out an issue with the docker image, I manually issued a docker run command using the same image on the same ECS instance and the container started as expected. Has anyone faced a similar issue? Is there a solution/workaround for this issue?

Also, the same application docker image when launched using fargate launch type (with a compatible task definition) runs correctly on Windows Server 2019 proving that there are no issues with the application's image as such.